# Prove that $x^n$ is a convex function on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

### Intention

The clear solution is to **use the fact that $x^n$ is twice differentiable**. But I want a more direct proof. To be clear I want to prove this result without referencing the idea of a derivative.

### My work

I decided to start with the inequality I wanted to prove, and work backward to an inequality that is obviously true.

Start with
$$(ax+by)^n\leq ax^n+by^n\quad (1)$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers such that $a+b=1$. Then (1) can be rewritten as

$$(a-a^n)x^n+(b-b^n)y^n-\bigg(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{n\choose k}(ax)^k(by)^{n-k}\bigg)\geq 0$$

I am stuck here.

Comment: What are you willing to assume without proof? For example, mid-point convexity ($a=b=1/2$) follows from the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality), then convexity follows by continuity.

Comment: Dividing by $y^n$ you see that you only need to prove for $y=1$. So you need to show $$(ax+(1-a))^n\leq ax^n+(1-a).$$ for any $a\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing by $y^n$, we see that you only need to prove it for $y=1$.  So you need that:

$$(ax+(1-a))^n\leq ax^n+1-a,\text{ for all }a\in[0,1].$$

Rewrite this as:

$$(1+a(x-1))^n\leq 1+a(x^n-1)$$

You can prove this by induction:

$$\begin{align}(1+a(x-1))^{n-1}&\leq 1+a(x^{n-1}-1)\\
(1+a(x-1))^{n}&\leq\left(1+a(x^{n-1}-1)\right)(1+a(x-1))\\
&=1+a(x^{n-1}-1)+a(x-1)+a^2\left(x^{n}-x^{n-1}-x+1\right)\\
&\leq 1+a(x^n-1)+(a^2-a)(x^{n-1} - 1)(x-1)
\end{align}$$

But $\alpha^2-\alpha\leq 0$  and $(x^{n-1}-1)(x-1)\geq 0$, so you get:

$$(1+a(x-1))^n\leq 1+a(x^n-1)$$

Comment: Would it be possible to briefly elaborate on why dividing by $y^n$ leads to only needing to prove for $y=1$? Is it just that the resulting inequality (from dividing by $y^n$) implies our desired inequality, and this resulting inequality is the inequality for when $y=1$?

**Also**, where does the proof fail for if $0<n<1$? Is it just that the induction itself cannot be used (since we cannot consider n-1)?