# Prove that $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^p$ for $p\geq 1$ is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> Prove that $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^p$ for $p\geq 1$
>   is convex.

I tried using this chain of inequalities:$$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\leq \frac{f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}\leq \frac{f(x_6)-f(x_5)}{x_6-x_5}$$ if $a<x_1<x_2\leq x_3 <x_4 \leq x_5 <x_6<b$. Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you know about the connection between convexity and the second derivative?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387353/prove-that-xn-is-a-convex-function-on-0-infty

Comment: Matrin R, I don't.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function: A twice differentiable function of one variable is convex on an interval if and only if its second derivative is non-negative there.

Comment: Let me put it another way: I know that, but I can't use it.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: Then please update your question: What do you know, what can you use? (And what is $p$? An integer, a real number?)

Comment: In the link saying that this problem is duplicate, the exponent is an integer and it has been proved using induction. Here the exponent is a positive real number.(I apologize to Aqua for my distraction in putting my comment in the wrong place).

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-Applying a known theorem about convexity, the proof is immediate since $p\ge1$ (*Take a look at Aqua's answer*). If you want to explicit a proof for the particular case of your exponential functions you can do as follows (among other possibilities).

►It is easy to verify that the arc of the curve between the origin and an arbitrary point  $(a, f (a))$ is convex because this segment has equation $y(x) =\dfrac {f (a)}{a}x$ for $0\le x\le a$.

►It follows that if $b\gt a$ the arc of the curve from   $(a,f(a))$ to $(b,f(b))$ is also convex because if not then there is a point $c$ in the interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(c)$ two distinct values. Can you see why? Help you with the attached figure.

[image]