# Prove that prove that $E[X^k] \le E[X]^k$ for any even integer $k\ge 1$

Tags: probability, expected-value

**Question.** Let $X$ be a random variable then prove that $E[X^k] \le E[X]^k$ for any even integer $k\ge 1$.

**Proof.** I am proving by using mathematical induction. For $k=1$ it is easy to see that it is true.
Assume that it is true for $k=j$, which means $E[X^j] \le E[X]^j$. Now to show that $E[X^{j+1}] \le E[X]^{j+1}$. Write  $E[X^{j+1}]=E[X^{j}X] \le E[X^j]E[X]$ and $E[X]^{j+1}=E[X]^{j}E[X]$.

After this I am not getting how to proceed further. I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: This is inequality is not true.

Comment: Thanks I have edited the question.

Comment: Also your proof is buggy, how do you get $E[X^jX]\leq E[X^j]E[X]$?  And your edits do not help, the statement is still false. Try some basic examples to see counter-examples.

Comment: @ Michael Yes I am attempting to prove it.

Comment: You want $\geq$ not $\leq$.  This is typically proving using convexity (Jensen's inequality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supposed inequality $E[X^k]\le (E[X])^k$ is not always true: Let $X$ be a random variable that takes the value $0$ with pribability $\frac{9}{10}$ and the value $10$ with probability $10$. Then with $k=2$: $$E[X^2]=10>1=(E[X])^2.$$

The inequality $E[X^k]\ge (E[X])^k$ for all $k \ge 1$ isn't always true either. Let $X$ be a random variable taking the value $0$ with probability $9/10$ and $-10$ with probability $1/10$.
Then for $k=3$:
$$E[X^3]=-10<-1=E[X].$$

If $X$ is a **nonnegative everywhere** random variable however, then the inequality $E[X^k]\ge (E[X])^k$ holds for $k\ge 1$ by Jensen's Inequality. [The function $f(x)=x^k$; $k >1$; is convex on the **nonnegative** reals but not the entire real line if $k$ is odd.]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering that it may be proved with mathematical induction.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the statement is not true. Your proof is wrong since you are falsely assuming that $X$ is uncorrelated with itself, which is impossible. To see why, suppose that there exists a random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb E[X^2] = \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[X]$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\mathbb E[X] = 0$ and $\mathbb E[X^2] = 1$ (if $X$ does not have mean zero and variance 1, just consider $Y := \frac{X - \mathbb E[X]}{\sqrt{\mathbb E[X^2]}}$, and note that $\mathbb E[Y] = 0$ and $\mathbb E[Y^2] = 1$). So $$1 = \mathbb E[X^2] = \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[X] = 0.$$ Obviously, this is not true.

However, it is true that $\mathbb E[X^k]\geq\mathbb E[X]^k$ for every **even** $k\in\mathbb N$. The statement can be proved using [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality): Let $k\in\mathbb N$ be even. Then $X^k\geq 0$ and the function $f(x) = x^k$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$ (see [Prove that $x^n$ is a convex function on $(0,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387353/prove-that-xn-is-a-convex-function-on-0-infty)).